# Need recommendation for device tracking system

Tags: dashboard, tracking

I have encountered this problem.

This is my problem:

- I have a fixed IP Linux server.
- I have ~100 Raspberry Pi's spreading around the city. The raspberry Pi are connected to internet but have floating IPs.
- The Raspberry Pi's have special sensors attached to them and need to report the sensor values to the Linux server periodically.
- the linux server needs to log the sensors values.
- the linux server also have a web server to allow user to view the existence of Raspberry Pi's and the sensor values.
- User is also allowed to send message to the Raspberry Pi's in order to, for example, turn on a light attached to them.

  If I were to implemented this / use existing framework to do this, what is the best way? Can someone gives recommendation?

Comment: Welcome to the forum. A couple of questions: 1. how often is the data send periodically e.g. every 5min, 1hr, 8hr, etc? 2. Roughly how much data is sent each time e.g. DeviceId, Time, SensorValue? You will probably have to code something yourself maybe based on http/REST/json to send periodically to the server. Hence you may not get advice in the forum since it is about software recommendations. Not sure if an existing generic framework exists, but you never know... You should also try other forums like stackoverflow etc.

Comment: You should also look at https://emoncms.org/ as may be related/similar to what you are doing.